# Importing "minted"s from a subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: minted, import, directory

My hierarchy goes like this:

```
Main Folder
    SubFolderForCode(1)
        doc.tex
        code.py
    SubFolderForCode(2)
        doc.tex
        code.py
    SubFolderForDoc
        doc.tex
```

I want to import code from `/SubFolderForCode(n)/code.py` to `/SubFolderForDoc/doc.tex` via the `\inputminted{python}{code.py}` command, but unfortunately the code seems to be unreachable unless I add `../SubFolderForCode(n)` before the actual code file name, which is understandably cumbersome. To work around this issue I used the `import` package as well:

```
/SubFolderForDoc/doc.tex
\import{../SubFolderForCode(n)/}{doc.tex}

/SubFolderForCode(n)/doc.tex
\inputminted{python}{code.py}
```

Unfortunately, even with the `import` package, I still seem to need preceding `../SubFolderForCode(n)` before the actual code file name. So my question is:

How can I input code (via either `minted` or `listings`, though I would prefer `minted`) by writing the relative directory from `/SubFolderForCode(n)/doc.tex`, and then accumulating the `/SubFolderForCode(n)/doc.tex` files in one main file? The main file would preferably not be in the highest directory, and there are a lot of `/SubFolderForCode(n)`s.

Comment: simplest would be to use `\def\mdir{/SubFolderForDoc}... \inputminted{python}{\mdir/code.py}` (If you use some tex-level path search to find the file you have the complication of also passing the file location to pygments commandline which is possible, but this is a lot simpler if it is acceptable)

Comment: I agree that setting a macro would be the simplest solution, though I can't help but wonder if there is a way to set relative paths of relative paths...or something along those lines.